# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime using DateTime.ParseExact C#

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

Thought I solved this issue, but I am still having a problem with it.  Trying to run this code to parse a Date and Time from user input in a prompt, but evertime I try to DateTime.ParseExact I get an error invalid format.  Sample Date : Jul 24, 2015 9:08:19 PM PDT 
Jul 26, 2015 2:13:54 PM PDT

```
        string afterpromptvalue = Prompt.ShowDialog("Enter earliest Date and Time", "Unshipped Orders");
        string beforepromptvalue = Prompt.ShowDialog("Enter latest Date and Time", "Unshipped Orders");

        string format = "MMM d, yyyy h:m:s tt PDT";
        CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        DateTime createdAfter = DateTime.ParseExact(afterpromptvalue, format, provider);
        DateTime createdBefore = DateTime.ParseExact(beforepromptvalue, format, provider);`enter code here`
```

Here's the code for the prompt box:

```
public static class Prompt
{
    public static string ShowDialog(string text, string caption)
    {
        Form prompt = new Form();
        prompt.Width = 500;
        prompt.Height = 150;
        prompt.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        prompt.Text = caption;
        prompt.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        Label textLabel = new Label() { Left = 50, Top=20, Text=text };
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox() { Left = 50, Top=50, Width=400 };
        Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Ok", Left=350, Width=100, Top=70, DialogResult = DialogResult.OK };
        confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close(); };
        prompt.Controls.Add(textBox);
        prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
        prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
        prompt.AcceptButton = confirmation;

        return prompt.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK ? textBox.Text : "";
    }
```

Comment: what is the format that you get as an input?

Comment: Do you mean what is in my `afterpromptvalue` and `beforepromptvalue` strings after the user input?

Comment: try this string format = "MMM dd, yyyy h:m:s tt PDT";

Comment: @DeshDeepSingh but it needs to be able to parse a date and time because I need this information for querying amazon for information on pending orders.

Comment: yes exactly, thats what i am concerned about

Comment: It threw the same exception.

Comment: now also set the time format as hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering of your both string, you just need to use [`mm` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#mmSpecifier) instead of [`m` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#mSpecifier) since your single digit minutes has [leading zeros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading_zero).

```
string format = "MMM d, yyyy h:mm:s tt PDT";
```

As an example;

```
string s = "Jul 24, 2015 9:08:19 PM PDT";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "MMM d, yyyy h:mm:s tt PDT", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // 24.07.2015 21:08:19
}
```

and

```
string s = "Jul 26, 2015 2:13:54 PM PDT";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "MMM d, yyyy h:mm:s tt PDT", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // 26.07.2015 14:13:54
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The input you gave is not the same as expected , you enter minutes with 2 digits instead of one. Since your expected time format is h:m:s, you cannot provide 9:08:19, but you need to enter 9:8:19.

See for correct format usage msdn link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hm.. I thought 'h' can be used with ether 08 or 8 but 'hh' must be used with 08. @Joel 's code worked just fine and printed the correct output to console.  If what you say is correct, I should get an error and the code wouldn't execute?

Comment: Actually, I cannot check it right now but according to MSDN, I though that your input is maybe wrong. If it is not the case, I will be able to help later

Comment: I checked your code and it works fine for me. I get an error only once when I put by mistake a space at the end of the input. I just copied & paste your code on a new project, run it and enter as input the strings you gave in the beginning

Comment: Yeah, weird.
Although you are setting the culture to invariant, I could think only on regional setting that could be the problem. Did you try to change it (maybe reset, not sure).

Answer (score 1):

try this:
problem might be you are converting to date time with specific format but not giving the same as input:

```
dateString = "Sun 15 Jun 2008 8:30 AM -06:00";
      format = "ddd dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt zzz";
      try {
         result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
         Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
      }
      catch (FormatException) {
         Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick check on your code via Console program and it reveals to my PC that it is working properly:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Globalization;

    namespace DateTimeConvert
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                var text1 = "Jul 24, 2015 9:08:19 PM PDT";
                var text2 = "Jul 26, 2015 2:13:54 PM PDT";

                string format = "MMM d, yyyy h:m:s tt PDT";

                var date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(text1, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                Console.WriteLine(date1);

                var date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(text2, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                Console.WriteLine(date2);

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it possible for you to run the above code and see if it still throws the same exception? There might be some other areas that needs to be checked.

Comment: The above code worked.  I added also `Using System.Threading.Tasks;` and `Using System.Text;`

Comment: I think the problem is with my prompt but I don't know what it is because the string in the variable `afterpromptvalue` is correct.

Comment: I think there might be a possibility that empty spaces are trigerring the format exception. You can try trimming those trailing spaces `afterpromptvalue.Trim()` and `beforepromptvalue.Trim()` and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks Joel I got to go to bed now but I'll try it tomorrow at work

Comment: Ah shoot! I thought that would work Joel, but it didn't ;(.  Not sure what to do maybe re do my prompt code, I had copied it from somewhere, I'll try and go over to understand it better.